# iPhone/Objective C: How can I get the UIButton instance from NIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I placed 1 UIButton on nib, and when user click this button,an IBAction method connect to it with a *Status* param.

What I want is, user click button and pass the Status to the IBAction method, and in that method, I need access the instance of the button.

How can I get the button's instance without an (id) sender here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wire up the UIButton with an outlet like you did with your IBAction to connect it.

In your header add:

```
UIButton *myButton;

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

And then link the new outlet with your button in IB.

Then you can access the button with myButton in your instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
// button is the instance of your button

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why without `(id) sender`? And what do you mean by that anyway? The `sender` argument of the action method is a reference to the button's instance. All you have to do is cast it to the proper type:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
```

Comment: en~~ because this button is the only button to handle the action, I think the 2nd answer is what I need. Anyway, thanks for you help~

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet variable for UIButton and connect via nib